# purpose of Daytime servers

Tags: rfc

Can someone please tell me what is the purpose of daytime servers? I referred to some sites like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol), but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What is a daytime server?

Comment: Some are telling that there are nothing called Day time server. please reffer this. http://www.vorlesungen.uni-osnabrueck.de/informatik/networking-programming/notes/15Nov96/7.html

Comment: Currently it looks like the answers provided are just copies of the intro to the link you have provided :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Daytime Protocol is for computers to communicate a widely accepted known format [RFC 867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc867) allowing the 2 computer systems to agree on the exact time and date to the current second.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a server its a protocol that might be supported by a server. Daytime Protocol works over TCP or UDP

A useful debugging and measurement tool is a daytime service. A daytime
service simply sends a the current date and time as a character string
without regard to the input.

Check this

```
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc867
```